# Error in magento script file

Tags: magento-1.7, error, setup-script

I have used this file for an extension of mine to add a new table but it doesn't run and gives error. Here is the code for my script.

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ` magebuzz_testimonial_store`;
CREATE TABLE ` magebuzz_testimonial_store` (
  `testimonial_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `store_id` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Testimonials Store Table';

");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Can anyone please tell me where am i going wrong with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you could post the error as well...

Comment: It just says Error in file: You have a syntax error in your file on line number 4 near ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Testimonials Store Table'' But there is just comment on line number 4 and code starts after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of the comma after the `store_id` field:
It should look like this:

```
$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$installer->getTable('magebuzz_testimonial_store')}`;
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('magebuzz_testimonial_store')}` (
  `testimonial_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `store_id` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Testimonials Store Table';

");
```

I also added a `$installer->getTable()` statement around the table name. This is in case you have table a prefix.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Just a bit of edit. The curly brace that started near $installer needs to be ended at the end of the same line.

Comment: Right. My bad. sorry. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When running into issues with a MySQL installer script it's always smart to just run the query in PHPMyAdmin for example to see if it returns any errors.

Optionally use PHPMyAdmin or [MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to create tables and use the export functionality to get the required Query. This way you are sure your query is correct.